# Loan Amortization Quarterly Payments

Tags: excel, excel-tables, amortization, excel-template

Has anyone got a loan amortization table in excel for loans with payments every four months? I need to calculate the payment amount for a loan that will pay three times a year 20 times

Comment: https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=loan+amortization+table+excel&oq=loan+amortization+table&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l5.7604j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: Doesn't quarterly mean 4 times per year?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is *not* a [programming question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), but...

- [**Quarterly**](http://www.yourdictionary.com/quarterly) means **4 times per year** (every 3 months), and 20 payments would take 5 years.
- **3 payments per year** is called [**Triannually**](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/83427/282305) and will take 6 years and 8 months.

I'm pretty sure you meant ***quarterly***.

---

A quick search found:

> ### Loan amortization schedule template
>
> Create a loan summary and payment schedule based on the terms of the initial loan with this loan amortization schedule template.  This is an accessible template. *(Excel)*
>
> [image: img]
>
> ### [Download Template](https://omextemplates.content.office.net/support/templates/en-us/tf03986974.xltx)

<sup>([Source](https://templates.office.com/Loan-amortization-schedule-TM03986974))</sup>

Comment: I meant triannually then. I guess this template will work anyways. thank you very much